# Fill remaining width in first row instead if last row in CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have container with multiline flexbox and some `div`s in it. If there is a different count of divs in the last row than in the other rows, divs will be larger because of `flex-grow: 1`. Is there any way to fill remaining width in the first row instead of last row?

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 |        |  1  |  2  |
-------------        -------------
| 4 | 5 | 6 |  -->   | 3 | 4 | 5 |
-------------        -------------
|  7  |  8  |        | 6 | 7 | 8 |
```

I don't know width of container, width of child div or count of children, so I cannot set width manually. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rfuvzqh2/1/) is example.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 10rem;
}

.reverse {
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

div {
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
Corrent order, wrong layout:

<section>
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div>
</section>

Correct layout, wrong order:

<section class="reverse">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below properties to first two div elements, basically 1 and 2.

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-basis: 46%;
```

Or else you can use `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse` and explicitly define the order in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick using `nth-child` combined with `nth-last-child` to target the first and second element. We basically have two cases where you need the first one to be full width or the first and second one half width:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 10rem;
  border:2px solid;
}

div {
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

section > :nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3n + 1) {
   flex-basis:100%
}

section > :nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3n + 2),
section > :nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3n + 1) {
   flex-basis:40%
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div>
</section>


<section>
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div>
  
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

To me this seems like a good place to use CSS Grid when you're making a layout in two directions. You can try something like this:

```
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: .5rem;

}

.grid div{
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid div:nth-child(-n+2){
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```